# How to updates array values in iphone app

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have to updates array values at position 2 and 4. How will I update array values. I am initializing my array like below.

```
ArrayrData=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:statuses]; // where statuses is also an array
```

Comment: [ArrayrData insertObject:anObject atIndex:2];
[ArrayrData insertObject:anObject atIndex:4];
?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change the value of NSArray. So initialize your array as Mutable Array

```
NSMutableArray *ArrayrData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[ArrayrData addObjectsFromArray:statuses];
```

You can update the value in a [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) using,

```
– replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:
– replaceObjectsAtIndexes:withObjects:
– replaceObjectsInRange:withObjectsFromArray:range:
– replaceObjectsInRange:withObjectsFromArray:
```

Comment: There's also `NSMutableArray *arrayData = [statuses mutableCopy]` that can replace the first two lines of your example :)

Answer (score 4):

Use the method

```
- (void)replaceObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index withObject:(id)anObject;
```

if u want to replace them with new objects or simply access the objects at index 2 and 4 and then modify them using

```
[ArrayrData objectAtIndex:idx]; //idx is the index of the object you want to access, in ur case it is 2 or 4.
```

Comment: [ArrayrData objectAtIndex:(2 or 4)]; is not real code. You should present that better.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the NSMutableArray dynamically in the application as follows:

```
NSMutableArray *ArrayData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[ArrayData addObjectsFromArray:statuses];
```

And now whenever you want to replace any object in array then you can simply replace using the "replaceObjectAtIndex" method as follows:

```
[ArrayData replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject:@"your Object or data"];
[ArrayData replaceObjectAtIndex:4 withObject:@"your Object or data"];
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: The Xcode dosen't shows any replcaeObjectAtIndex method as such..Any clue?